# How to import custom cerficate using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

How can i import a certificate like the command below but then using AWS CDK?

```
aws acm import-certificate --certificate file://Certificate.pem
                                 --certificate-chain file://CertificateChain.pem
                                 --private-key file://PrivateKey.pem
```

Answer (score 3):

Since CDK generates cloudformation stack behind the senses, this method is not supported.
Currently, you can achieve that by import the certificate to ACM, And later import the certificate using the certificate ARN.

Usage:

```js
import cert = require('@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager');
const certificateArn = "arn:aws:...";
const certificate = cert.Certificate.fromCertificateArn(this, 'CertificateImported', certificateArn);
```

More info about [cert.Certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-certificatemanager-readme.html).

Comment: But how do I use the certificate after I've imported it like in your example? Do I apply it to the route53 zone I also create? If you could give and example on that as well that would be great! :) Thanks!

Comment: What do you wish to create? please be more specific in order to provide relevant example

Comment: I tried this approach and the approach from documentation to add certificate in a ALB, but both doesn't worked.

I made this, and works for me:

const certificateArn = "arn:aws:acm:....;
const listenerPort443 = alb.addListener('listenerPort443', { 
  port: 443,
 });
listenerPort443.addCertificateArns('SSL', [ certificateArn ]);